# Outer table alias is not recognized in ClickHouse

Tags: sql, nested, clickhouse

I have a time series table in ClickHouse called kafkadata and I want to find out rows matching a certain range in past data with respect to incoming data timestamp.

For example, in past records, find all those records which match a range (-X, +X) where X is positive number in seconds; with incoming records.

For this purpose, I have built following query however, CH does not seem to recognize outer table alias within nested query.

```sql
select t2.`event`, t2.`timestamp`, t2.`ID`,
    (
        select grouparray(t1.`event`) as ge--, grouparray(t1.`ID`) as gid,
        from default.`kafkadata` as t1
        where t1.`timestamp` <= date_sub(second, 3, t2.`timestamp`)
            and t1.`timestamp` >= date_add(SECOND, 3, t2.`timestamp`)
        group by t1.`event`, t1.`ID`
    ) as ge
from default.`kafkadata` as t2
group by t2.`event`, t2.`timestamp`, t2.`ID`;
```

Error from ClickHouse

```bash
SQL Error [47] [07000]: Code: 47. DB::Exception: Missing columns: 't2.timestamp' while processing query: 'SELECT grouparray(event) AS ge FROM default.kafkadata AS t1 WHERE (timestamp <= (t2.timestamp - toIntervalSecond(3))) AND (timestamp >= (t2.timestamp + toIntervalSecond(3))) GROUP BY event, ID', required columns: 'timestamp' 't2.timestamp' 'ID' 'event', maybe you meant: 'timestamp', 'ID' or 'event': While processing (SELECT grouparray(t1.event) AS ge FROM default.kafkadata AS t1 WHERE (t1.timestamp <= (t2.timestamp - toIntervalSecond(3))) AND (t1.timestamp >= (t2.timestamp + toIntervalSecond(3))) GROUP BY t1.event, t1.ID) AS ge. (UNKNOWN_IDENTIFIER) (version 23.6.2.18 (official build))¶, server ClickHouseNode [uri=http://localhost:8123/default, options={use_server_time_zone=false,use_time_zone=false,session_timeout=1000000}]@-1581460642
```

Can anyone guide here, what is being wrong here and what is alternate option?

Comment: clickhouse doesn't support correlated subqueries, it is scheduled for 2023, but the year is almost finsihed

Comment: you subquery doesn't look right, but you can join  the correlated subquery and have so access to the columns

Comment: Did you try using a CTE (common table expression)? https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/with